# How to change .csv file from one folder to another after import to postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I am receiving .csv files in a folder to have an import and data, this sending of files is done every 10 minutes so that there is an update of the database.
I would like that after the import is done that .csv file would change folder to a processed files folder otherwise I will always be importing the same files without updating.
Is that possible?

Comment: You will need to provide more information about how the import of the CSV files is being done ? Though I am going to say that the file rotation is going to have to be done by a script external to the database.

Comment: The .csv file is being imported by a stored procedure using COPY

Comment: Well unless you are using one of the untrusted languages(plpython(3)u, plperlu) you cannot move the files from inside the procedure. So you will need to create a program external to Postgres that moves the files.